# Import all subclasses like Java but in C#

Tags: c#

This is such a dumb question, but I can't figure out the lingo to ask Google.

In Java if I wanted to import all subclasses I would use something like

```
java.util.*
```

And all of util would be imported.

Firstly, what is the proper lingo for what I'm doing in C# so I can start using Google more effectively.  Am I importing namespaces?  Libraries? Subclasses?  (Can you tell I'm new at this?)

Secondly, since I'm here, how is this accomplished in C#?

PS- I did click on every related question stackOverflow threw at me to see if the answer would pop up.  No luck.  I'm simply without words to describe what I'm looking for.  The example should do just fine but...  Anyone who can take a moment to either explain the lingo to me or perhaps simply point me at something that can (in a nutshell, I have a couple books for the long haul) that would be great.

Comment: You are importing namespaces.  There is no such construct in C#

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Firstly, let's differentiate between **assembly references** and **namespaces**.

Assemblies are what you add references to in your c# project, they are the libraries that contain the actual classes you need, usually found as DLL files. The .net framework contains many such assemblies, and Visual Studio will try to reference the most commonly used ones in your project (e.g. for a WinForms project it will automatically add a reference to `System.Drawing.dll`).

**Namespaces** are logical partitions of the classes in an assembly.

Once you reference an assembly in the project, all classes in all namespaces are available for use, if you provide their full name.

This is where the `using` directive comes in.
It is simply syntactic sugar for not having to write very long names all the time.

For example, assuming your project references the `System.Drawing.dll` assembly, you would have to qualify a class from this assembly using it's full name, for example

```
System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData
```

Because this is tiresome and bloats the code, if you start your `.cs` file with

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

you could then instantiate a class using just the name `BitmapData`.
This will be true only for the `.cs` file in which you added the `using` directive, not for the whole project.
Also, it's important to note that `using` one namespace does not bring in all nested namespaces, you have to `using` each one individually.

Comment: Thank you.  A very straight forward and well thought out reply.  Plus, now I know why I have to use the reference thingy in #Develop before I ever use `using` in my code.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

You must brush up on your your Google-fu

http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/java_csharp_comparison.html#namespaces

Comment: You are my hero.  Thank you a million!

Comment: No need for all that, I'll take 100 thousand :)

Comment: lol.  If I could accept two answers I would click that check box over there.  You certainly addressed my PS very well.  Thanks again :-).

Answer (score 4):

It can be called importing / referencing/ using namespace.

Such a language feature is not available in c#.

A little explanation: Namesspaces can be spread across multiple libraries. so when you use a namespace it may refer to it from multiple referenced assemblies.

Comment: Ah, okay.  So I import them as needed then.  Well, it should make for better coding practices at least, though I enjoy cheating at times...  Just to check if I do something like `code`using ExcelApi`code` that would not include `code`using ExcelApi.Utils`code` as an example?  I have to do both imports to get both levels of namespaces?

Comment: thats right.. put it simple.. using System and using System.Web are different.

Answer (score 2):

It's called `namespace` and it's imported by a keyword `using`. For example:

```
using System;
```

This statement enables you to reference all the classes that exist in that namespace. They, however don't enable you to reference any class in the subnamespace of declared `namespace`. You have to declare each `namespace` separately. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
```

Of course, you need to have a proper references added to the project where you're specifying the `using` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Within .Net, you first would need to ensure that there is a referenced assembly containing the namespace you would like to import.  Once that reference exists, you can use the 'using' directive to bring that namespace into the class so as to not have to fully qualify all object names.  You can find more information on this directive [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

If I misunderstood, let me know and I'll do my best to get you pointed in the right direction.